# Copy files matching a number pattern within a range

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a directory in Ubuntu containing about 1M files with names starting with numbers like:

```
1-filename-438573_45785.json.gz
2-filename-419805_47894.json.gz
4-filename-230071_00394.json.gz
5-filename-230071_00394.json.gz
...
1000000-filename-345675_909090.json.gz
```

Note that some files(numbers) are missing.

I want to copy the files starting with names from 1 to 10000 so I've tried:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{4}-.+' |xargs cp -t {destination}
```

However, when I get the list of files found, I am getting the ones with file numbers from 1000 onwards.

How can I fix the regex to get the whole range needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU find:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/([0-9]{1,6}|1000000)-.+'
```

output:

```
./5-filename-230071_00394.json.gz
./2-filename-419805_47894.json.gz
./1000000-filename-345675_909090.json.gz
./4-filename-230071_00394.json.gz
./1-filename-438573_45785.json.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it seems that the only problem may be related to the regex. I would try this regex instead: `'.*/([0-9]{1,4}|10000)-.+'`.